# Multiline Search and Replace in Atom editor

Tags: regex, atom-editor

I want to find this:

```
<p>
various text and code
</p>
```

...and replace it with completely different text. Atom doesn't seem to have a multi-line RegEx flag. How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The regular expression `(.|\r?\n)*?` is what you're looking for.

Used in the example above, `<p>(.|\r?\n)*?</p>` will select all three lines and you can then either replace or delete those lines.

Comment: For me this only finds instances where the opening and closing para tags are on a single line :( (I'm on v 1.16.0 ia32)

Comment: is where a way without regular expression?

Comment: @Wlad that will be up to the makers of Atom to implement this as a proper feature. (Dear creators of Atom: please?)

Comment: This works, but only on a single file (ctrl-F), for multiple files (ctrl-shift-F) it seems to not find it. I have not found a workaround.

Answer (score 4):

Try the regex `[\s\S]*?`, with your example `<p>[\s\S]*?</p>`

see also https://github.com/atom/find-and-replace/issues/303